# C++ win32-type project is unavailable

Tags: c++, winapi, libraries, lib, project-types

I use Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition for C++, but I have a problem.
I need to create a win32 project (Actually I want to create a static library (.lib)) but for some reason I don't have this type of projects available!
All what I have in the Section of Visual C++ is:

- Windows Desktop

  - Windows Console Application
  - Windows Desktop Application
  - Windows Desktop Wizard
- Windows Universal
- General

  - Empty Project
  - Makefile Project
  - Shared Items Project
- ALT

  - ALT Project
- Test

  - Native Unit Test Project
- Qt

What should I do to get Win32 Project Template?
or is there another way to create such a project (.lib NOT .exe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop Wizard should allow to select "Static library" on first or second page.